# How to dynamically check existing user in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

in my web application I have register form for new user. There is also one field  username:

```
    TextField<String> username = new TextField<String>("username");
    username.add(UsernameValidator.getInstance());
```

when user push button then username is validate. But this behaviour is not user friendly. Is there some options how to validate this dynamically and if there is error in validation user cant push button ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the: [OnChangeAjaxBehavior](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/OnChangeAjaxBehavior.html)

```
  username.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {

     @Override
     protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //do stuff here
     }
  });
```

Comment: yes I know this but I dont know how to disable push button when there is error inside this behavior

Comment: `button.setEnabled(Boolean.FALSE); target.add(button)` ?